# How to get info from this html using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get all the social link of a company from [this](https://craft.co/snapdeal). When doing

`summary_div.find("div", {'class': "cp-summary__social-links"})`

I am getting this

```
<div class="cp-summary__social-links">
<div data-integration-name="react-component" data-payload='{"props":
{"links":[{"url":"http://www.snapdeal.com?utm_source=craft.co","icon":"web","label":"Website"},
{"url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/snapdeal?utm_source=craft.co","icon":"linkedin","label":"LinkedIn"},
{"url":"https://instagram.com/snapdeal/?utm_source=craft.co","icon":"instagram","label":"Instagram"},
{"url":"https://www.facebook.com/Snapdeal?utm_source=craft.co","icon":"facebook","label":"Facebook"},
{"url":"https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/snapdeal?utm_source=craft.co","icon":"cb","label":"CrunchBase"},
{"url":"https://www.youtube.com/user/snapdeal?utm_source=craft.co","icon":"youtube","label":"YouTube"},
{"url":"https://twitter.com/snapdeal?utm_source=craft.co","icon":"twitter","label":"Twitter"}],
"companyName":"Snapdeal"},"name":"CompanyLinks"}' data-rwr-element="true"></div></div>
```

I also tried getting children of `cp-summary__social-links`, which I want indeed and then find all `a` tag to get all the links. This does not work too.

Any idea, how to do this?

**Update:** As Sraw suggested, I managed to get all urls by doing like this.

```
urls = []

 social_link = summary_div.find("div", {'class': "cp-summary__social-links"}).find("div", {"data-integration-name": "react-component"})
    json_text = json.loads(social_link["data-payload"])
 for link in json_text['props']['links']:
     urls.append(link['url'])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they `a` tags? It seems it is a json-like string. You can extract the value of `data-payload`, and use `json.loads` to parse it.

Comment: `a` tags comes in first child of `cp-summary__social-links`, which is itself the same `cp-summary__social-links` class. Btw, how to get data from `data-payload`?

Comment: @Sraw, See [this image](https://pasteboard.co/H3BwMgI.png) for html dom tree of mentioned class.

Comment: There isn't `a` tags inside page. Those `a` tags are created by js dynamically according to the value of `data-payload`.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Sraw.